# How to delete duplicate MySQL tables rows while keeping at least one row

Tags: mysql

I have four columns all of which are `varchar(x)`.

- DealerId
- FirstName
- LastName
- StreetAddress

Then I have one `int` column that is auto incremented called `SystemId`.

What I want to do is delete all the rows in my table where the 4 columns match but I want to leave the row with the greatest auto incremented id.

For example

```
SystemId|DealerId|FirstName|LastName|StreetAddress
1|Hello|Mike|Tola|1923 somewhere dr
2|Hello|Mike|Tola|1923 somewhere dr
```

In the above example I want to delete `SystemId 1` and leave `SystemId 2`. I have about `300k` rows so grabbing those id’s one by one are out of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a straightforward join:

```
delete t2
from mytable t
join mytable t2 on t.dealerid = t2.dealerid
  and t.firstname = t2.firstname
  and t.lastname = t2.lastname
  and t.streetaddress = t2.streetaddress
  and t.systemid > t2.systemid
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa3a4/1)

The trick is the comparison of `t.systemid > t2.systemid`, which keeps highest (last added) id.

Comment: With an index on the four columns, this should perform better than my solution.  Without an index and lots of rows to be deleted, my solution will probably perform better.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a `join`:

```
delete t
    from table t join
         (select t2.dealerid, t2.firstname, t2.lastname, t2.streetaddress,
                 max(t2.systemId) as maxsystemid
          from table t2
          group by t2.dealerid, t2.firstname, t2.lastname, t2.streetaddress
         ) t2
         on t.dealerid = t2.dealerid and t.firstname = t2.firstname and
            t.lastname = t2.lastname and t.streetaddress = t2.streetaddress and
            t.systemid < t2.maxsystemid;
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
delete from table_name
where SystemId IN
(select t1.SystemId from table_name t1, table_name t2 where t1.DealerId=t2.DealerId and t1.firstname=t2.firstname and t1.lastname=t2.lastname and t1.streetaddress=t2.streetaddress and t1<t2  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way by using a join on the maximum of SystemId

```
DELETE t
FROM mytable t
LEFT JOIN 
(
SELECT MAX(SystemId) SystemId
  FROM mytable
 GROUP BY DealerId,FirstName,LastName,StreetAddress

) t2
ON(t.SystemId = t2.SystemId)
WHERE t2.SystemId IS NULL
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b966b/1)